# Install different versions of a package on different platforms with poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

In my project, I need to support both Linux and Windows, so I followed [these](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#multiple-constraints-dependencies) guidelines and added these lines to my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = [
    {url="https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl", markers="sys_platform=='win32'"},
    {url="https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl", markers="sys_platform!='win32'"}
]
```

(In addition I tried `os_name=='nt'`)
but when I try to run `poetry update`, I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeError]
The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - [dependencies.torch] [{'url': 'https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl', 'markers': "sys_platform=='win32'"}, {'url': 'https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl', 'markers': "sys_platform!='win32'"}] is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

What is the right way to install different versions of the same package on different platforms using Poetry?

Comment: Tried `platform_system=='Windows'`?

Comment: Yes. Similar results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known bug, and there's a [PR with a fix](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/1819), although it's not merged or released yet